# How to allow users to add images in a text editor (TinyMCE)

Tags: html, forms, input, tinymce

I am currently using TinyMCE on my site for the text editor and it's great but it does not allow the user to add images unless you pay for the moxiemanager add-on.

I just wanted to know if they was any other way to allow the user to do this other than buying the addon?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with Power Paste Plugin: **[here](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/powerpaste/)**

*please, consider reading [these article](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/get-started/upload-images/)*

Comment: You have to pay for that too